# Accent conversion in googleappengine and python

Tags: python, unicode

I am writing a language tester app for a class in mobile apps and have a problem straight away with converting accents so it can be displayed using the self.response.write().  Here is an example with a French accent

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        word = "médecin"
        self.response.write(word)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

When I run this I get

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
500

If I take out the accented letter and write "mdecine", it shows this word in the browser.  I have Googleappengine etc. all setup and this is not the issue.

Any examples I find on utf8, encode etc. are mostly for command line Print and not working here.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? The meaning of `"médecin"` is very different between Python 2 (where it's a bytestring encoded in some unspecified way) and Python 3 (where it's a well-defined Unicode string).

Comment: The default is 2.7.  Another one was the gaelic "Fàilte" (welcome), though I hope its the same principle for any of these.

Comment: Got it! Added # - *- coding: utf- 8 - *- at the top. Probably not the best way.

Comment: @tagliatelli ... In Python2.7 ... you have to specify encoding scheme beside the default one which is `ascii`, and as your string contains non-ascii chars...then it won't be displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2, the default encoding for source files is `ascii`, as @iron-fist observed.  If a source file contains a non-ascii character, even in a comment, Python will raise a `SyntaxError`:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file
>   /home/user/path/to/main.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see
>   http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

There are two ways to get round this:

1. You can declare an alternative encoding for the file using an
   encoding cookie, as you have done by adding 
   `# - *- coding: utf- 8 -*-` to the top of you file.
2. You can use the escaped form of the non-ascii character(s) in
   unicode strings: `word = u'm\xe9decin'`

Option (1) is the easier to work with, in my experience.  There's a discussion of this, and unicode in Python2 in general in the [Unicode HowTo in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).